# On the limit of $S(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$ when $x\to 0^+$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Sorry I haven't any ideas.
Maybe it equals ${1 \over 2}$.
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$$

Comment: Why do you think the limit exists, to begin with?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(1-2^{1-x})\zeta(x) = (1-2)\zeta(0) = \frac12$$.

Comment: because

(i)$\mid \sum (-1)^{n-1}\mid<1 $ ,

(ii)for every $x\in (1,+\infty),{1 \over n^x}\searrow$,

(iii)${1 \over n^x}\rightrightarrows 0$

according to Dirichlet's test

$\Rightarrow$
  
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$ converges.

Comment: @achillehui,awesome!

Comment: @GEE20151011, I suppose the inquality in your comment is weak.

Comment: @Timbuc ,sorry I made a mistake.(ii)should be (ii)for every $x\in (0,+\infty),{1 \over n^x}\searrow$.

Comment: @GEE20151011 Yes. Achille's comment wraps this up, although the tagging of your question didn't hint about using the Riemann zeta function and its analytic continuation by means of the Dirichlet's Eta function

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Timbuc can this be solved without zeta function?

Comment: I'm not sure @avz2611 . Probably not, and besides this I'm a huge fan of the zeta function. I just didn't take it into account looking at the tagging. Not even complex analysis was tagged.

Comment: @Timbuc ,I'm sorry about the tag,this question is asked by my friend.And he didn't give me any hint.

Comment: Oh, don't worry for that @GEE20151011 : I just loved the question and the way achille answered it.

Comment: Oh k, I just haven't encountered zeta function or the dirichlets test, so was asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the comment, the easiest way to evaluate the sum is using
[Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(1-2^{1-x})\zeta(x) = (1-2)\zeta(0) = \frac12$$

However, it is possible to evaluate the sum without it. We can start from following integral representation of $\frac{1}{n^x}$,

$$\frac{1}{n^x} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)} \int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-nt} dt$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
and derive an integral representation of the sum.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x} 
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-nt} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\int_0^\infty \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} e^{-nt}\right) t^{x-1} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^t + 1} d t^{x}\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{t^{1/x}} + 1} dt
\end{align}
$$
As long as $x > 0$ and we keep manipulating the terms in the sum in unit of pairs,
everything is non-negative and we won't have any issue of exchanging the order of summation
and integration.

In the limit of $x \to 0^{+}$, the integrand converges pointwisely to a step function $\theta(t)$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{e^{t^{1/x}} + 1} = \theta(t) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\begin{cases} 
\frac12,& t \in [0,1)\\
\frac{1}{e+1}, & t = 1\\
0, &t \in (1,\infty)
\end{cases}$$
It is clear for small enough $x$, the integrand is dominated by some Lebesgue integrable
function over $\mathbb{R}$. We can then use
[dominated converge theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
to justify the exchange of order of taking limit and integration. As a result, we find

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \sum_{n-1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1)} \int_0^\infty \theta(t) dt = \int_0^1 \frac12 dt = \frac12$$